# Accessing service is too much slower than accessing inside container

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8s cluster, and the version of k8s is **v1.12.1**. One of the services is below:

```
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/flask   NodePort   10.99.101.226   <none>        8090:32010/TCP   15h
```

When accessing the service with `CLUSTER-IP` inside the cluster, it is very slow compared to accessing inside the pod container.

```
curl  10.99.101.226:8090/test_json > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2316k  100 2316k    0     0   263k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  216k
```

```
kubectl exec -it flask-example-77dbd59654-2g857 -- sh
/app # curl localhost:8090/test_json > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2316k  100 2316k    0     0  75.3M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 75.3M
```

The former speed is only **216K**, but the latter speed can up to **75.3M**, I wonder to know what cause the difference.

Is there anyone can help me? thanks.

Comment: Are you getting all similar results if you run the test multiple times right after each other so it's not just startup time related?

Comment: I tested multiple times, and the result is similar

Comment: Localhost isn't a real network adapter and traffic on it passes through a lot fewer layers. That is probably related at least.

Answer (score 0):

There's the latency of your network connection.

When you access it by exec'ing into the pod, there's no hop at all as you are on the same host and network, but the `NodePort` service expose your app through your `node`, so your connection will need to go first from your machine to the Node and then bypassed to the pod.

[your machine] <==> [NODE]:32010 <==> [POD]:8090

To have a clear view on what's happening, you can use `--trace` and you should be able to see the hops:

```
curl  --trace trace.log 10.99.101.226:32010/test_json > /dev/null
```

then check the file `trace.log`

To avoid hit the node and access the pod directly, you can use a headless service. You can do that by changing the service type to `ClusterIP` and set `clusterIP: None` on the `spec`

Comment: The requested json file is a little big, and the result is not possible to paste here.

Comment: I think it's not caused by latency of network connection, I execute the command inside the cluster, so the latency should be very short and I accessed directly with `clusterPort`

Comment: try this `curl --trace log.txt 10.99.101.226:8090/test_json` and check the `log.txt` file to see the hops

Comment: if you want to avoid hitting the cluster, why don't you try to run you service as a headless service?
you could simply change the service type to `ClusterIP` and set `clusterIP: None` on the spec

Comment: I'm not sure if it is host network. I checked `log.txt`, there is only one hop

Comment: If you are running the command from the cluster, there’s still the hop from the cluster to the pod. Which could mean there’s some issue with the CNI.

Comment: Have you tried to start another pod in the same namespace and run the curl from one pod to the pther using the pod ip?

Comment: I run curl from one pod to the other using the pod ip, and the speed is about 438K.

Comment: in this case, it seems like the communication to containers is slow... that can be multiple things... I suggest searching on kubernetes github issues for `slow pod to pod communication`, like [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41078) that suggest to enhance performance by disabling ipv6